# JDOMParseException: Error on line -1: Premature end of file

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I'm getting that exception when reading an InputStream with JDOM's SAXBuilder's `build` method:

```
InputStream bais = p_sendXML.getXml().getInputStream();
File myFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), PREFIX+p_sendXML.getSessionId()+".xml");
IOUtils.copy(bais, new FileOutputStream(myFile));
LOGGER.debug("File save in: "+myFile.getAbsolutePath());
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document xmlDoc = builder.build(bais);
```

The File is correctly created and the XML inside is valid, so I shouldn't get this exception. There is a new line at the end of the XML file, if you are wondering.

Comment: In which line of code?

Comment: The `build` one. I edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 'exhausted' the `bais` when you did `IOUtils.copy(bais, new FileOutputStream(myFile));`. You have copied the contents of the `bais` to the file, and now the `bais` is 'empty'. You will need to either:

1. take a copy of the `bais` somehow before writing it to disk
2. Parse it directly by JDOM and use JDOM to write the XML to disk (`XMLOutputter`)
3. get JDOM to parse the file (not the `bais`).

Comment: @pHCito don't kick yourself over this one. These things happen, and it is why a second set of eyes helps. The reason for SO (the right reason). (can you tell that I have been stuck by things like this before...?)